# set position {0,0} of element accessibillityTitle via Applescript

Tags: applescript, windows, ui, dialog

I have a UI element called `accessibillityTitle` with value `Layers` and I want to position this element in the top right corner, but I don't know how to acces it via Applescript. I have found the element using `Accessibility Inspector` and here is what the rest looks like.

```
AXApplication
    AXWindow:AXDialog
Attributes
    isAccessibilityFocused  NO
    accessibilityTitle  Layers
    accessibilityGrowArea   <nil>
    accessibilityMinimizeButton <nil>
    accessibilityDocument   <nil>
    accessibilityCloseButton    <nil>
    isAccessibilityMain NO
    accessibilityFullScreenButton   <nil>
    accessibilityProxy  <nil>
    accessibilityDefaultButton  <nil>
    isAccessibilityMinimized    NO
    accessibilityChildren   10 items
    accessibilityRole   AXWindow
    accessibilityParent <AXApplication>
    accessibilityTitleUIElement <nil>
    accessibilityCancelButton   <nil>
    isAccessibilityModal    NO
    accessibilitySubrole    AXDialog
    accessibilityZoomButton <nil>
    accessibilityRoleDescription    dialog
    accessibilityToolbarButton  <nil>
    accessibilityFrame  x=1038.00 y=23.00 w=240.00 h=773.00
    accessibilityIdentifier com.pixelmatorteam.pixelmator.layers.palette
Actions
    accessibilityPerformRaise
```

How can I use `set position to {1280, 0}` to this element?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I dealt with a similar case, when I wanted to move a previously generated dialog to the top-right corner of my screen.
I only succeeded in doing so ***thru a 2nd script*** that was launched *simultaneously*, but had a "repeat nothing until" loop built in to await the dialog's pop-up. In my experience, no matter what I tried, the dialog would hinder an "in-script moving" while its window stayed open ...
*(I attached both to a folder: I just had to add #2 to its list.)*

In script #1 the final command reads:

```
tell application "Finder" to display dialog DL_display as string with ¬
  title "Recent downloads" buttons {"Close"} default button 1
```

The 2nd one:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set screenRgt to bounds of the window of desktop  --> independent of
    set rightEdge to (item 3 of screenRgt) - 425      --> screen resolution
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    repeat while not (exists window "Recent downloads")
    end repeat
    delay 0.1
    set position of window "Recent downloads" to {rightEdge, 61}
end tell
```

You can see there's a (minute) delay after "repeat-nothing". Even waiting 0.1s sometimes my MacMini's so busy that the delay's too short, and the dialog remains centered ...
(To make sure set a higher value, say: 0.5.)
My "Recent downloads" Workaround #2 for Safari can be found [***HERE***](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216674/can-safaris-download-popover-window-be-made-wider/218138#218138).